# Umbraco Cannot Access to Website After Migrate From Localhost to Webhost

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I am using Umbraco 7 and use SQL Server 2014 as the database.

It doesn't have any problem in localhost. But after I upload it to webhost, also I import the database to the webhost database, I cannot access my website. Instead of it should show my website, but it will redirect to ADMIN LOGIN page. Moreover, I even cannot login to the admin panel.

Is it something wrong with the database?

I already change the connection string in Web.Config

Answer (score 2):

Check the logs in the umbracotracelog.txt file that can be found in /App_Data/Logs/. That should give you any error message that's occurring. You can also try and log in with Chrome inspector or similar running and see if the POST to the login controller returns a 500 response.

It sounds like a DB connection issue. Check that the database connection string is correct, and that it works (e.g. try logging into the database using the details in your connection string using SQL Management Studio or similar). It could be the username or password are incorrect, or the the website can't reach the database for some reason.

Comment: I don't know what error would occur if the web host isn't set up for Full Trust, but that might also be an issue.

Comment: I just solved the problem... It is because of the database problem.

Instead of using Generate Script and execute the script to webhost database, I use SQL Server Import & Export Wizard...